# How to represent a Java array in javascript of a Java Web Project?

Tags: javascript, java

Assume I have following code in a jsp file in JavaWeb:

```
<%
String myList = new String[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    myList[i] = String.valueOf(i);
}
%>
```

Now I want to get the value of the elements of myList in a loop of javascript:
Are the following ways are correct?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = new Array(10);
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    arr[i] = "<%=myList[i]%>"
}
<script>
```

If not, how could I reach my purpose?

Comment: Well, if it works then it's probably correct. Otherwise no. Does it work?

Comment: I haven't test it yet. But commonly it is not right because the value i is the value of javascript and it can not be used in java code in <% %>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing array from .jsp to javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731041/passing-array-from-jsp-to-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Look at there [Passing array from .jsp to javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731041/passing-array-from-jsp-to-javascript-function)

No, this isn't correct. Because the jsp i will never change.